# Pitch accent of months?

Tags: pitch-accent

I'm having some trouble identifying a pattern/rule in the pitch accent for months.

For example, the 4-mora, 2-kanji 三月 is HLLL (頭高) while 六月、七月、八月、十月 are LHHH (平板/尾高). (As is usually the case.)

For 二月, [OJAD](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:invisible/limit:20/word:%E5%9B%9B%E6%9C%88) states it is HLL (頭高) while [NHK](https://www.amazon.co.jp/NHK%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8-%E6%96%B0%E7%89%88-NHK%E6%94%BE%E9%80%81%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%E6%89%80/dp/4140111127/) states it is LHH (平板/尾高). My native speaker girlfriend says that both are fine, but she also says 四月 as HLL (頭高), while both dictionaries claim it is LHH.

Are the pronunciations of these words just super flexible? If so, is there some simple rule of thumb I can follow?

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも… https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/049.html　`尾高型：1、2、4、6、7、8、10、11、12月　頭高型：3、5、9月　ところが、本来尾高型の2月と4月を、頭高型で［ニ＼カ゜ツ］［シ＼カ゜ツ］と発音する人が増えています。間違えないように「頭高はゴー、サンキュー」と覚えておきましょう。`

Comment: Thanks, this article is a perfect explanation. It is from 2001, though. Would you say that most people still ignore this advice and go with 頭高 for 二月 and 四月?

Comment: I think many people still pronounce them as [にがつ]{HLL}, [しがつ]{HLL}, though I wouldn't say *most* people do. (People more commonly pronounce them that way in the West Japan, so the western dialectal pitch pattern might have influenced on their pronunciation in Standard Japanese.) I don't think you need to worry so much unless you're a professional broadcaster or Japanese language teacher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 二月　HLL(me)　　LHH(NHK)
>   二月四日　HLL(me) ≧ LHH(me)
>
> 四月　HLL(me)　　LHH(NHK)
>   四月四日　HLL(me)　≧ LHH(me)

I'm a native and I live in Yokohama since about 50 years ago.

I noticed two things:

1. The names of the two months concerned have only one syllable. Confusion may likely occur between them when spoken with a small voice or low pitch at the biginning like LHH. Therefore, we seem to become to speak them naturally with loud voice or with high pitch at the beginning of them like in HLL even both pronunciations are allowed.
2. The pitch is different when saying only the name of the month and when saying the month and the date together.
   Even in the latter case, I think that the previous noticing is involved. For example, when 二月四日 is pronounced, 二月 is usually known in the conversation, so what you only have to listen to clearly is 四日. Therefore, 二月 may be allowed to be pronounced lightly. So if two pronunciations are allowed, 二月 may be pronounced in LHH pitches, which is sometimes hard to listen to.

By the way, although 四月 is claimed to be pronounced as LHH in both dictionaries, I think that this is a phonologist's preferred expression, and I usually pronounce the word expressed by this mark **flatly** without placing an accent anywhere with my intention like **LLL** not like HHH.

---

### Bonus

In my answer I wrote that in order to clearly convey one-syllable words, we devise to pronounce them in a loud voice or we put a pitch accent on the starting point of the word like HLL, even it is claimed to be pronouced in LHH or flatly.

I think that this device is applied to the Japanese who speak with standard pronunciation and accent including myself, but I would like to introduce different measures that the Kansai dialect takes so that one-syllable words could be heard more clearly.

When the Kansai people pronounce a one-syllable word like "[木]{ki} *tree*", "[酢]{su} *vinegar*" or "[手]{te} *hand*", instead of placing an high pitch accent at the begininng of it, they would enlong the vowel and add the same vowel after the enlonged one like 酢 *suh-u*.

The way to pronounce it is to lower the pitch gradually from the begining of the word to the enlonged vowel and to raise the pitch suddenly at the lastly added vowel.
In this way, they pronouce a one-syllable word as much as two to three times long.

By doing this, enough time could be secured for listeners to hear the pronounced one-syllable word. I think the Kansai people are clever.

I do not know why, but regarding the pronunciation of 二月 and 四月, I think that the Kansai dialect does not use its good device.

Comment: I have only ever heard 二月 as HLL but I have also definitely heard 四月 as HLL, LHH, and LLL by different people, so what you're saying makes sense

Comment: Chocolate has posted this useful [NHK link](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/049.html) above, which gives the advice that 二月 and 四月 should be LHH, as HLL is a "harsh accent/耳障りなアクセント". 

However, from your statements, mackygoo and psosuna, I'm wondering if this is just a pedantic stylistic choice for broadcasters. Would you say that it is safe in normal conversation to stick with HLL for 二月 or 四日? Does LHH sound odd?

Comment: @kennysong: At first, I appreciate you for giving me an interesting question. As for your question in the comment, I think that to pronounce them in HLL pitch accent is not "耳障｛みみざわ｝り", so I recommend you to pronounce them like HLL as ordinary people do, including me. As a bonus, I'm going to post a relating topic by editing my answer. So give me a time.

Comment: Regarding the last remark, under Tokyo accent there's considered to be an **automatic rise** after the first mora (unless the first is accented), staying flat high until the end of the word or the accent mora, whichever comes first.  So a phonological LLL (or, in some notations, '---' – unspecified pitch) is realized as LHH.  Notice that there's also phonological LLH′ (--H′), with accent on 3rd, which is also realized as LHH; they can be distinguished by the following particle. A 'flat' or 'unaccented' word, LLL/---, results in LHH-H; while phonological LLH′/--H′ results in LHH-L.

Comment: @leoboiko: May be you are correct. I think I speak in Tokyo accent and I speak a flat or unaccented word with the intention of being unaccented, but the result of the sound uttered may be measured like LHH, which must be a custom without my intention.

Comment: @mackygoo Yes, that's what we mean by "phonological" or "underlying" flat pitch (the way you, as a native speaker, feel it) versus the "phonetic", "surface" or "automatic" rise in pitch (which is how we non-natives feel it). By the way, thank you for taking your time to write this detailed answer; your input as a native is valuable for many of us.

Comment: `Kansai people pronounce a one-syllable word... raise the pitch suddenly at the lastly added vowel` We Kansaians pronounce 木, 手,
目 as [きい]{LH}, [てえ]{LH}, [めえ]{LH}, 歯, 毛 as [はあ]{HL}, [けえ]{HL}, 蚊, 血 as [かあ]{HH}, [ちい]{HH}. 1モーラの語は関西では HL, LH, HH のどれかになりますね

Comment: @mackygoo Thanks for the point about the Kansai dialect. Just want to clarify about 二月 and 四月, it seems like it is equally okay to pronounce them as LHH (as per leoboiko's comment, originally written by you as LLL).

Comment: 基本的にLLL...っていうピッチの語はありません・・・助詞が続いたときに、「[○○○に]{LLLH}」とか「[○○○は]{LLLH}」などとなるものはないので。「しがつ」がHLLなら「[しがつに]{HLLL}」、LHHなら「[しがつに]{LHHL}」、HHHなら「[しがつに]{HHHL}」で、[しがつに]{LLLH}はないです

Comment: @Chocolate: >基本的にLLL...っていうピッチの語はありません　＊その通りだと思います。英語を習ったとき、アクセントがあるところを「’」で表すと教えられます。日本語にアクセントがあるのに気づいたのは関西弁を知った時です。まさか、日本語のアクセントが「’」ではなく、HやLで表すとはこのサイトに来るまで知りませんでした。これは言語学者やＮＨＫや日本語を外国人に教える場合に便利だと思います。しかし、この度の話題を含め、日本語は音の高低でアクセントを表すと言い切るのは不十分な気がしております。実際は音の高低と音の強弱を併用しているような気がします。更に、日本人が**意識して**使い分けているのは音の強弱であって音の高低ではないような気がします。発音するとわかりますが、音を強く発音すると音程が上がります。従って**HLL**と表記される単語については**意識と音程の結果に相違がでません**が、私がフラットと感じるLHHと表記される単語では、相違が出ます。音の強さをか●で表すと、HLLは●●{HLL}、LHHは[●●●]{LHH}またはLHHです。自分が意識している音は音の強さですが、音の高低はいつの間にか覚えたくせのようなものでしょうか。カラオケのコンテストなどで音程がフラットな出だしでのみ１音目を下に外す歌い手が多いのが生きた例でしょうか。

Comment: `日本語は音の高低でアクセントを表す‌​と言い切るのは不十分` はい、以前[ここ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/why-is-the-reading-of-%e7%9e%ac%e3%81%8f-and-%e7%9e%ac%e3%81%8d-not-the-same/47043#comment84174_47043)でも書きましたように、HL方式でアクセント・イントネーションを100%表すことはできません。

Answer (score 0):

You can try FORVO for checking the pronounciation
https://forvo.com/word/%E4%BA%8C%E6%9C%88/#ja

Three of four speakers pronounce 二月 as LHH, and one (from the US) pronounces it as HLL.

As a rule of thumb 月 (gatsu) and 日 (nichi) are 尾高 when they follow accented number, and 頭高 when they follow nonaccented number (3,5,9) (9 is considered nonaccented only as く, when it's きゅう it's considered accented).